# how to wait for the result of an asynchronous function nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to get the hang of using Mongoose promises with the async/await functionality of Node.js.
However I have problems with the second "find" function because is linked to the first one, i think because i dont have the first find result. 
How can I wait for the response of the first function and then execute the second?

```
exports.permissions_Check2 =  async function(params){
  const Sessioni = require('../models/Sessioni');
  const Permessi = require('../models/Permessi');
  const express = require ('express');
  var token= params['Token'];
  var tabelle = params['Tabelle'];
  var DataSession= [];
  var out;
  try{
  const sessioni = await Sessioni.findOne({token: token}).exec();
  const permessi =  await Permessi.findOne({IDGruppo: sessioni.IDGruppo}).exec();

  out={
    IDAccesso: sessioni._id,
    IDUser: sessioni.IDUser,
    IDGruppo:sessioni.IDGruppo,
    Permessi: permessi
  }
  return out;
  } catch (err){
    return  err;
  }

  return  out;

}
```

**output:**
 {
  IDAccesso: "ehwuhf7867tgyb",
  IDUser: 1,
  IDGruppo: 1,
  Permessi: null }

Comment: Your function is working just fine.
It has been set to null as expected. Undefined is what it should be returning in case of the permesi function not waiting for the response or a Promise object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Promises? 
That will look like

```
  Sessioni.findOne({token: token})
  .exec()
  .then(sessioni => {
    Permessi.findOne({IDGruppo: sessioni.IDGruppo})
    .exec()
    .then(permessi => {
      out={
        IDAccesso: sessioni._id,
        IDUser: sessioni.IDUser,
        IDGruppo:sessioni.IDGruppo,
        Permessi: permessi
      }
     }).catch(e => throw e);
  }).catch(e => throw e)
```

I'm not sure what DB you're using, but hope that will help